# How to ensure a server's source code and binaries are the same as the standard?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, architecture

I have seen the on-premise equipment having a design to deal with unauthorized modifications, e.g. a client's staff wants to resolve a technical issue by DIY (do it yourself), not willing to call the official customer service.

The design was to validate the files by checksums, so if a checksum does not match the record, it indicates that the corresponding component is changed. And the feature helps narrow down the issue in troubleshooting when a certified technician arrives on site.

I am currently working on a failover test, so I need to ensure that the active and standby servers have the same installation, including the source code, scripts, binaries, configuration files, installed PRM packages, etc.

Not sure if I should write my script following the thoughts of checksum above. Or maybe the Linux (Red Hat) ecosystem provides a more handy and standard solution.

I will highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

Comment: Only use digitally signed executables and compare the secure hash of the original to the file that is deployed.

Comment: use a tool such as chef/ansible/puppet/terraform etc to configure your machines. They will do all this work for you.